# Import multiple projects in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have a number of projects in my Eclipse workspace, some of them plain ol' Java projects, some of them Java web applications, some of them Flash Builder Flex projects.

They all live in a directory hierarchy. How can I open all of them in IntelliJ IDEA to be able to migrate from Eclipse to IDEA? The projects reference each other.

Comment: Multiple projects in IntelliJ IDEA = 1 project and X modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an IntellIJ IDEA Project from source using the `Import Project` in the main menu.

Select the eclipse `.project` file or `.classpath` then check `Link created IntelliJ IDEA modules to Eclipse project files`.

The official docs, [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/importing-eclipse-project-to-intellij-idea.html):

> To import an existing Eclipse projects to IntelliJ IDEA:
>   Open the New
>
> Project Wizard. Having selected the option Import project from
>   external model, click Next.
>
> On the Import page of the New Project
>   Wizard, select Eclipse. Optionally, check the option Import into
>   current project. Click Next.
>
> On the next page of the wizard, specify
>   the directory, that contains the desired Eclipse workspace. In the
>   section IntelliJ IDEA project and module file location, specify
>   whether you want to create IntelliJ IDEA module files in the same
>   directory where the Eclipse projects reside, or in a dedicated
>   directory of your choice.
>
> Check the option Link created IntelliJ IDEA
>   modules to Eclipse project files to automatically synchronize the
>   Eclipse projects and IntelliJ IDEA modules.
>
> Specify whether you want test sources to be imported.
>
> Click Next. IntelliJ IDEA scans the specified workspace for projects.
>
> On the next page of the wizard, select the Eclipse projects you want
>   to import. So doing, each Eclipse project is converted to a separate
>   IntelliJ IDEA module. Click Next. Specify the name for the new
>   IntelliJ IDEA project, and the location of the project files.
>
> Select also the format in which the project will be stored. Click Finish.

[image]

If you select "Keep project and modules in" you could separate eclipse project and IntelliJ IDEA project files

I never did something like this, but after reading docs and playing a bit the options it should be the best way.

Comment: Now it is "New > Project from Existing Sources" - they keep changing it!